# Can we / how do we use the iOS speech engine?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, text-to-speech

I'd like to use the iOS speech engine in my app to speak some text. Is this available to developers and if it is how do we use it?

Comment: Which speech engine: VoiceOver or Siri?

Comment: Erm, one which will speak text from a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CMU Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) libraries offer pretty good text to speech, with a few voices. You give it text and it outputs a .wav file, which you can play through AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Accessibility (VoiceOver) APIs are readily available to developers, and have been for years. Siri, however, is another issue altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock While there are accessibility APIs for defining how VoiceOver speaks your UI elements, you cannot access the text-to-speech engine directly, i.e. you cannot make it speak any text when VoiceOver is not enabled (which it usually isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7, you can use the native [AVSpeechSynthesizer class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer).